# In Liquibase, how to add a new column/field to an existing composite primary key

Tags: oracle, liquibase

We have an *existing table*, with 2 existing columns that serve as a composite primary key.  They were set up very similarly to this:

```xml
<!--  WE CAN NO LONGER MODIFY THIS CHANGESET  -->

<changeSet author="an_awesome_author" id="EXAMPLE-01">
  <createTable tableName="our_awesome_table">
    <column name="source" type="varchar(32)">
      <constraints 
          primaryKey="true" 
          nullable="false" 
          primaryKeyName="CPK_OUR_AWESOME_TABLE"/>
    </column>
    <column
        name="external_id"
        type="varchar(255)">
      <constraints 
          primaryKey="true" 
          nullable="false"  
          primaryKeyName="CPK_OUR_AWESOME_TABLE"/>
    </column>
  </createTable>
</changeSet>
```

---

It has subsequently come to our attention that there can be multiple records with the same `source` & `external_id` ([image: twitching eye]).  The group submitting the data submits on a regular schedule and they've assured us that they never use the same combination of `source` & `external_id` in the same batch of data.

So (for reasons beyond this question) we've decided that we're going to add a `created_at` field, that is non-nullable and defaults to when each record is added to the table.  That's not that difficult, e.g. we can run this pair of `changeSet`s

```xml
<!-- WE ARE TRYING TO FINALIZE THESE CHANGESETS -->

<changeSet author="yours_truly"
           id="EXAMPLE-02-01">
  <addColumn tableName="our_awesome_table">
    <column name="CREATED_AT"
            type="datetime"
            valueDate="current_datetime"
            defaultValueDate="current_datetime" />
    <!-- the above:
      adds the new field
      sets the type
      adds the current timestamp to existing records
      will default to the current timestamp for new records
    -->
  </addColumn>
</changeSet>
<changeSet author="yours_truly"
           id="EXAMPLE-02-02">
  <addNotNullConstraint tableName="our_awesome_table"
                        columnName="CREATED_AT"/>
  <!-- the above:
    now that every record has a value in the newly created field,
    we can add a constrant preventing null entries into the column
  -->
</changeSet>
```

---

***BUT, we also need to add `created_at` to our existing composite primary key!***

If I try to include the primary key as a constraint when we're creating the field it complains about the table only being able to have one primary key —*despite the fact that it's already a composite key and I'm only trying add this to the already in existence composite key.*  But it also complains about the `created_at` timestamp being null.  So, I'm not sure which is the actual problem ‍♂️, but it definitely doesn't work here.

e.g.

```xml
<changeSet author="yours_truly"
           id="EXAMPLE-02-01">
  <addColumn tableName="our_awesome_table">
    <column name="CREATED_AT"
            type="datetime"
            valueDate="current_datetime"
            defaultValueDate="current_datetime">
      <constraints primaryKey="true"
                   primaryKeyName="PK_OUR_AWESOME_TABLE"/>
      <!-- this constraints causes multiple problems -->
    </column>
  </addColumn>
</changeSet>
```

results in something like:

```sh
[ERROR]      Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ORA-02260: table can have only one primary key
[ERROR]  [Failed SQL: ALTER TABLE OUR_AWESOME_TABLE.OUR_AWESOME_TABLE ADD CREATED_AT TIMESTAMP DEFAULT SYSTIMESTAMP PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL]
```

---

If I try to include the primary key as a `<constraint>` in the changeSet where we add the non-nullable constraint then I'm basically told that I can't use `<constraints>` there and instead need to one of a list of `<addXxxConstraint>` and in the list is an `<addPrimaryKey>` —this sounds like the right constraint.

So if I change the second changeSet to something like this, I would expect it to work:

```xml
<changeSet author="yours_truly"
           id="EXAMPLE-02-02">
  <addNotNullConstraint tableName="our_awesome_table"
                        columnName="CREATED_AT"/>
  <addPrimaryKey tableName="our_awesome_table"
                 columnNames="CREATED_AT"
                 primaryKeyName="CPK_OUR_AWESOME_TABLE"/>
</changeSet>
```

*But* —as you can probably guess— it doesn't work.  Instead, it informs me that, `cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'primaryKeyName' is not allowed to appear in element 'addPrimaryKey'.`

---

***So, how can I add a new non-nullable field, to an existing composite primary key?***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no primaryKeyName attribute for the [addPrimaryKey](https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/community/add-primary-key.html)-Type - The name of the constraint can be set via `constraintName`.

But it won't work since you cannot alter primary keys in oracle. Instead you have to [drop the primary key](https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/community/drop-primary-key.html) (and most probably the corresponding index) and then recreate it including the column you want inside the `columnNames`:

```
<changeSet author="yours_truly"
           id="EXAMPLE-02-02">
  <addNotNullConstraint tableName="our_awesome_table"
                        columnName="CREATED_AT"/>

  <dropPrimaryKey tableName="our_awesome_table"
                 dropIndex="true"
                 constraintName="CPK_OUR_AWESOME_TABLE"/>

  <addPrimaryKey tableName="our_awesome_table"
                 columnNames="external_id, created_at"
                 constraintName="CPK_OUR_AWESOME_TABLE"/>
</changeSet>
```